# Set connection string for SQL Server in Plesk for aspnet core application (this is not a true question but a explanation on how to do it)

Tags: connection-string, plesk

I was trying to set this parameter and was having difficulty with it.

In the Plesk database section i had the database i wanted to use. First i had to make a dump of the database i was using locally with my aspnet core project. I used SQL Management studio to access the database on the SqlExpress Server, that is the one that is installed with visual studio and the one that is used by default when creating a application with user login template. The sqlExpress server name is (localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB.
Still on the SqlManagment studio, i selected the database, right-mouse click, Tasks, dump database.
On the plesk management area, on the database sections, i made a import of that file for the specific database i wanted to use. Then clicked the check button and it was ok.

Then the hardest part was to figure out what connection string to use, and even, what is the name of the server?
Solution in answer.

Answer (score 1):

On the Plesk database area, on the specific database there is a "Connection info" which gives us the following info:

---

### Host ------------------- .\MSSQLSERVER2019 
Database name --- myspecificdb_
User name ---------- myusername
Password ----------- myPassword123+

And the connection string we should have on our appsettings.json is...

"DefaultConnection": "Data Source='.\MSSQLSERVER2019';User ID=myusername;Password=myPassword123+;"

Now, why it works without specifiyng the database name is a mistery to me. If anyone knows please feel free to explain.

So the correct way is:
"DefaultConnection": "Data Source='.\MSSQLSERVER2019';User ID=myusername;Password=myPassword123+;Database=myspecificdb_;"

Comment: It works w/o specifying the database bc plesk sets a default database for the sql server user has a